# «Более двум тысячам» или «более чем двум тысячам» — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление, наречия, части-речи, счетный-оборот

*Двум тысячам рабочих выдадут премию.*

Выдадут (кому?) — тысячам, тысячам (скольким? каким?) — двум.

А если рабочих более двух тысяч, то как правильно сказать и объяснить падежи?

*Более двум тысячам рабочих выдадут премию.*
*Более чем двум тысячам рабочих выдадут премию.*

"Более" и "более чем" — это какая часть речи?

Comment: "Более чем двум тысячам" правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правилен только *второй* вариант (*более чем двум тысячам рабочих*), поскольку сочетание "*более стольких-то единиц*" не изменяется по падежам из-за неизменности своего первого элемента "*более*", который при этом управляет оставшей частью (*двух тысяч рабочих*) таким образом, что она *неизменно* находится в *родительном* падеже. Возможен только винительный падеж *всего* сочетания (*нанять **более двух тысяч рабочих***), который по форме совпадает с именительным. По этим причинам для остальных падежей всего выражения **более** трансформируется в сочетание **более чем**, которое позволяет произвольно выбирать падеж счётного сочетания "две тысячи рабочих".

В данном контексте "более чем" выступает как *элемент неразложимого сочетания* со счётным оборотом (с которым образует единый член предложения) и имеет значение сравнения. Он не требует разделительной запятой, ввиду отсутствия сравниваемых понятий, см. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_68 .

В других контекстах ("более чем прилично" и т. п.) "более чем" может выступать как самостоятельное *наречное сочетание* со значением "совершенно, в высшей степени", см. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_789 .

Comment: Как-то у вас очень неаккуратно сформулировано: *"...в **родительном** падеже. Возможен только **винительный** падеж этого сочетания...  который по форме совпадает с **именительным**"*. Я понимаю, что вы хотите сказать, но надо бы как-то почетче.

Comment: Да, пожалуй. Заменил "этого" на "всего" и выделил его дополнительно жирным шрифтом.

Answer (score 3):

[**бо́лее**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5), ***сравнит. ст.; нареч.***
**1.** = Больше (1-2 зн.). *Ваш шпиц — прелестный шпиц, не более напёрстка* (Грибоедов).
**Более чем...**
**I. *в зн. нареч.*** Совершенно, в высшей степени, очень. *Более чем интересно. Ваше выступление более чем возмутительно.*
**II. *в зн. частицы.*** *Это странно. — Более чем странно.*

Начнем с того, что Ваши первичные рассуждения неверны.
*Выдадут (кому?) — тысячам, тысячам (скольким? каким?) — двум.*

Нет, так не пойдет. Правильно:
**тысяча** (кого? Р. п. мн. ч.) **рабочих**; **две** (чего? Р. п.) **тысячи рабочих**;
**выдадут** (кому? Д. п.) **двум тысячам рабочих**.
*Две тысячи рабочих* — это счетный оборот, который изменяется по падежам и **весь** является одним членом предложения.

Наречие "более" требует после себя родительного падежа (в том числе и счетного оборота):
более (чего?) миллиона книг; более (чего?) всего; более (чего?) десяти тысяч рублей; более (кого?) трех тысяч человек; более (кого?) двух тысяч рабочих.
Вывод: говорить "Более двум тысячам рабочих выдадут премию" нельзя, потому что после глагола "выдать" нужен дательный падеж, а здесь родительный.

Присутствие "более чем" в счетном обороте на его обычное склонение не влияет:
И. п. кто? — более чем две тысячи рабочих;
Д. п. кому? — более чем двум тысячам рабочих;
Т. п. кем? — более чем двумя тысячами рабочих.

Можно только так:
***Двум тысячам*** рабочих выдадут премию.
**Более чем двум тысячам** рабочих выдадут премию.